# Count duplicates from several files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, terminal, text-processing

I have five files which contain some duplicate strings.

**file1:**

```
a
```

**file2:**

```
b
```

**file3:**

```
a
b
```

**file4:**

```
b
```

**file5:**

```
c
```

So i used `awk 'NR==FNR{A[$0];next}$0 in A' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5`

And it prints `$ a`, but as you see there is `b` string 3 times repeated in other files, but print only `a`.

So how to get all repeated string (`a` `b`) from analysing/comparing every file with each other using one line command?  Also how do I get the number of repeats for each element.

Comment: do you want repeats handled differently if they occur within 1 file vs occurring across multiple files? If so what is the different behavior you want?

Comment: @EdMorton however i got solution from below answers. i just want because i want repeated value from looking every file with compare to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use one of these;

```
awk '{count[$0]++}END{for (a in count) {if (count[a] > 1 ) {print a}}}' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

or

```
awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

you could test this for a=3  and b=4.

```
awk '{count[$0]++} END {for (line in count) if ( count[line] == 3 && line == "a" || count[line] == 4 && line == "b" ) {print line} }' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

test:

```
$ awk '{count[$0]++}END{for (a in count) {if (count[a] > 1 ) {print a}}}' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
a
b


$ awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
a
b

$ awk '{count[$0]++} END {for (line in count) if ( count[line] == 2 && line == "a" || count[line] == 3 && line == "b" ) {print line, count[line]} }' 1 2 3 4 5
a 2
b 3
```

Comment: thanks, it also working. is that possible to count repeated string like (a=3, b=4)?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest with GNU sort and uniq:

```
sort file[1-5] | uniq -dc
```

Output:

```
2 a
3 b
```

---

From `man uniq`:

> `-d`: only print duplicate lines
>
> `-c`: prefix lines by the number of occurrences

Comment: thanks. that work partially. because it also print non repeated word. suppose in file6 have C string then it also print C in output. *i edited question

Comment: thanks thats work. is this possible that we can count repeated string. like (a=2, b=3)

Comment: Replace `uniq -d` by `uniq -d -c`. Output: `2 a` and `4 b`.  Or replace `uniq -d` by `uniq -d -c | awk '{print $2"="$1}'`.

Comment: Thanks @cyrus for solving problem :)

Comment: Beacuse you changed content of file3 a shorter answer is possible. Thanks to @Thor.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{ a[$1]++ } END { for(i in a) if(a[i]>1) print i,a[i] }' file[1-5]
a 2
b 3
```

It counts the occurrances of each record (character in this case) and prints out the ones with count more than one.